# Kubernetes nginx ingress controller with opentracing does not show url resource path

Tags: nginx-ingress, opentracing

we use kubenrnetes nginx ingress controller version 0.25.1 on aws eks (kubernetes version 1.13).
we enable opentracing as per the documentation and use Datadog to view the traces. We have a general ingress rule to catch every path:

```
rule {
  host = "staging.example.com"
  http {
    path {
      backend {
        service_name = "cpe-test1"
        service_port = 80
      }

      path = "/"
    }
  }
}
```

In the Datadog ui we see the nginx traces, however the "resource" column always shows "/" rather than the full path which is "/test" or "/ping".
If we create a separate ingress rule for each resource path, then we see the full path as expected (i.e."/test" or "//ping") but it is very inconvenient and tedious to create a ingress rule for each path. is there any way we can see the full resource path in datadog UI without creating a separate ingress rule for each resource path?

Comment: I think it's not possible. Looking at [nginx-opentracing](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/nginx-opentracing/blob/master/doc/Tutorial.md) it creates paths based on `location` blocks and 1 `location` block is created per `ingress path` (`opentracing_operation_name` and `opentracing_location_operation_name` could change that, but those would still be static values).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by adding the annotation below to nginx ingress:

```
annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      opentracing_trace_locations off;
      opentracing_tag resource.name $uri;
```

See full answer at https://github.com/DataDog/dd-opentracing-cpp/issues/118